# How should I implement an unsubscribe feature for text messages?

Tags: web-development, web-applications

On many e-mail subscription lists, the is a link at the bottom that says something to the effect of:

> You are subscribed to our e-mail list as you@example.com. To unsubscribe, [click here](http://example.com/unsubcribe?code=you)

What is the best way (and is there a way?) to emulate this when sending out mass text messages through SMS gateway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

> Reply NO to unsubscribe

Then you can receive responses, extract the source phone numbers, and remove the numbers from the mass-sending list.

Most phones have a 'Reply to this SMS' function, and typing NO should not be excessively taxing.

You don't need a fancy unique number found in un-subscription URLs, since you have the source number in every incoming SMS.

Comment: Just don't require the user to enter some dumb code or something at the same time.  I have experience with one unnamed service that requires the user to enter in an application ID code to say yes,no, or any of the above during the subscription process.  Testing this on my own phone, which doesn't quote SMS replies, was a major PITA.